# Different class name based on condition in React

Tags: react.js, jsx

I have a very simple component, which should be styled differently based on the passed condition.

I wonder if there is a better approach to refactor this piece of code?

```
function RandomComponent({ number, condition }) {
    let classNameToUse;

    switch (condition) {
        case 'high':
            classNameToUse = 'number number--high';
            break;
        case 'medium':
            classNameToUse = 'number number--medium';
            break;
        default:
            classNameToUse = 'number';
    }

    return <div className={classNameToUse}>{number}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're just trying to decide between `number--high` `number--medium` or `''` based on the `condition` variable, then just make a helper function that does that

then do `return <div className={"number " + getNumberClass(condition)}}>{number}</div>`

Comment: Thanks, yeah I guess the best thing to do is to extract the selection into a separate function.